# Using vb.net to parse through json code with exception

Tags: json, vb.net

I am trying to use vb.net windows forms application to parse through some JSON code. My code builds just fine and compiles, but the moment I click on my button, I get this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

The exception is pointing to this line at the end of my code:

```
For Each item As JObject In JArray.Parse(jsonObjects.SelectTokens("items").ToString)
```

I have tried to solve it, but I don't know how to anymore. Here is my code:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim jsonString As String = "{""id"":1, ""name"":""tom"", 
""items"":[
    {""name"":""apple"", ""count"":1 },
    {""name"":""milk"", ""count"":2 }
]
}"
        Dim jsonObjects As JObject = JObject.Parse(jsonString)
        Console.WriteLine("id:" & jsonObjects.SelectTokens("id").ToString)
        Console.WriteLine("name:" & jsonObjects.SelectTokens("name").ToString)

        Console.WriteLine("items:" & jsonObjects.SelectTokens("items").ToString)
        'Dim jsonArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(jsonObjects.SelectTokens("items").ToString)
        For Each item As JObject In JArray.Parse(jsonObjects.SelectTokens("items").ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("item:" & item.SelectTokens("name").ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Exceptions always have an explanation associated with them; you did not share that information so we dont know what problem we are solving.  If you are trying to get more than just a few things, it might be easier to deserialize it into a collection of NET objects

Comment: Adding some details about the exception will help others analysis your question.   My first thought is you may need to add some custom handlers to help it correctly deserialize the JSON.  Take a look at the class Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter

Comment: You probably want to back up and examine those 3 `WriteLine` results - `SelectTokens` returns an `IEnumerable` of JToken and `ToString()` on them wont result in anything useful

Comment: I added more on the exception, sorry about that. @tatmanblue I have also looked more into the class, and I tried adding a bit more... but I am still getting the same exception

Comment: @Plutonix I got it working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I am trying to ... parse through some JSON`

Before you get to the exception at the loop start, this wont result in anything very useful:

```
Console.WriteLine("id:" & jsonObjects.SelectTokens("id").ToString)
```

`SelectTokens` returns an `IEnumerable(Of Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken)`.  Trying to display it with `ToString` will just result in:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JsonPath.FieldFilter+<ExecuteFilter>d__0
```

If you want several items from throughout the JSON it would probably be easier to deserialize it to a NET object or collection, but thats not what you asked.  This will list the items that Tom has:

```
Dim jobj = JObject.Parse(Candyjson)

' print the Id, name and how many items there are
Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}  Name: {1} has {2} Items", jobj("id"), jobj("name"),
                  jobj("items").Count)

' print each item name and how many there are 
For n As Int32 = 0 To jobj("items").Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine("Item: {0},  Count: {1}",
                            jobj("items")(n)("name"),
                            jobj("items")(n)("count")
                            )
Next
```

Results:

> Id: 1  Name: tom has 2 Items
>   Item: apple,  Count: 1
>   Item: milk,  Count: 2

One you parse the JSON, the resulting JObject will contains various other things depending on what is in the JSON.  If you set a breakpoint and examine `jobj`, the result will look much the same as your JSON (string), but it is in a form you can query:

[image]